# how to reset the value of a radio button in windows phone 7 application using c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a form in my windows phone 7 app which contains a few textboxes and a radiobutton. I want to reset the value of the textboxes and radio button on clicking the reset button. I am able to clear the textboxes but donot Know how to clear the value of the radio button. Please help:

My form is:

```
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="6" Height="74" Name="name" Text="*Name" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
            <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus1" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="66" Height="74" Name="age" Text="*Age" Width="453" BorderThickness="0" />
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="157" Height="44" Name="gen" Text="Gender" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" Width="134" />
            <RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="157" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" Content="Male" Height="71" Name="male" Width="154" />
            <RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="207"  FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" Content="Female" Height="71" Name="fem" Width="140" />
            <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus2" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="267" Height="74" Name="sadd" Text="*Street Address" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
            <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus3" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="327" Height="74" Name="cadd" Text="*City Address" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
            <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus4" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="387" Height="74" Name="eadd" Text="*Email Address" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
            <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus5" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="447" Height="74" Name="phn" Text="*Phone" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
            <TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus6" Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="507" Height="74" Name="zip" Text="*Zip Code" Width="453" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

My code for resetting on clicking the reset button is:

```
private void reset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        name.Text = "";
        age.Text  = "";
        sadd.Text = "";
        cadd.Text = "";
        eadd.Text = "";
        phn.Text  = "";
        zip.Text  = "";
    }
```

Please add the code that i should add here to reset the radio button

Now on clicking submit button if i want to check that whether male or female has been selected or not, how can i do that. For text box i am doing the following code:

```
   private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (name.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property named content which is equivalent to a textbox text property

And this is how you are gonna set it

```
male.IsChecked=false;
male.Content=String.Empty;
```

And regarding the edits.

assign a common groupname property to both the radiobuttons. ie

```
<RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="157" FontStyle="Italic" GroupName="Gender" Foreground="Black" Content="Male" Height="71" Name="male" Width="154" />
<RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="207"  FontStyle="Italic" GroupName="Gender" Foreground="Black" Content="Female" Height="71" Name="fem" Width="140" />
```

This makes either of the two selected everytime in xaml.

Now getting the value of a radiobutton in code should be like.

```
if(male.IsChecked==true)
{
string gender=male.Content.ToString();
}
else if(female.isChecked==true)
{
string gender=female.Content.ToString();
}
else    //none of them is selected.
{
 MessageBox.Show("Text");
}
```

Comment: Please see my edited code. I want to validate that field i.e, whether male or female is selected or not.

Comment: and a tip, name.Text == "" shall not be used, instead name.Text==String.Empty shall be used. Same for assigning as well.

Comment: I want to add a message box here that please select your gender. How will i validate the gender field